# How to display text in main window?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qmainwindow, qlabel

I'm new to Qt and I'm having a hard time finding a simple example illustrating how to display some text on the main window. For example, I just want to save some text in a string and display the contents on the main window. I thought to do something like this in the `mainwindow.cpp` but to no avail.

```
this->setText("Hello, world!\n");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do e.g. [this](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qlabel.html#text-prop) in your mainwindow constructor:

```
#include <QLabel>
...
QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
label->setText("first line\nsecond line");
```

There are various ways to display something like that, this is naturally just one of those, but it should get you going.

Here is a simple example showing this without a custom `QMainWindow` subclass:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QLabel>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow mainWindow;
    QLabel *label = new QLabel(&mainWindow);
    label->setText("first line\nsecond line");
    mainWindow.show();
    return application.exec();
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT += widgets
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `QLabel` somewhere in the `mainWindow` and then do

```
label->setText("Hello, world!");
```

Then the text will appear in the `label`.

Answer (score 1):

All widgets derive from the same base class, [QWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html), which can be displayed with a call to [show()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#show)

Therefore, at its most basic level, Qt allows you to create any widget and display it with minimal code, without even having to explicitly declare a main window: -

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QLabel *label = new QLabel(&mainWindow);
    label->setText("Hello World");
    label->show();

    return app.exec(); // start the main event loop running
}
```

Following on from this, each Widget can be provided with a parent widget, allowing the QLabel to be added to MainWindow (or any other widget), as shown by the answer provided by @lpapp